An asker indicates... should be 'reviewer' instead in the Staging Ground help page
I have noticed the following lines in the help article What is Staging Ground?


An asker indicates that your post is ready to leave the Staging Ground. Your question will then be posted directly to Stack Overflow.
An asker indicates that your post needs some minor changes, but is otherwise ready. You’ll be asked to revise your post, and then you can post it to Stack Overflow.


Askers do not necessarily indicate when other questions are ready or needs minor changes. Those should say 'reviewer' instead.
